# How to redraw view while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, core-graphics

I have a `UIScrollView`. This scroll view scrolls my custom `GameView`. When I send `setNeedsDisplay` to my `GameView`, it redraws and everything goes fine.

Except when I'm in the middle of scrolling `GameView`. It does not redraw until the scrolling has stopped.

Is there any way to circumvent this and just force the view during the scroll?

By the way, I already found these questions, but they didn't help:
[UIScrollView pauses NSTimer until scrolling finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605027/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-until-scrolling-finishes)
[How do I get my UIView to redraw while the user is scrolling a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729401/how-do-i-get-my-uiview-to-redraw-while-the-user-is-scrolling-a-uiscrollview)

Comment: I had this problem when using monotouch also, i forgot how i solved though

Comment: Where are you calling setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: In a method of `GameView`. That method gets called by my view controller when I get a network response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending the view's layer `displayIfNeeded` immediately after `setNeedsDisplay`.