# NSTimer stops during scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nstimer

During debugging my `IOS` project developed in `XCode4`, I initialize and run an `NSTimer` object. However, the timer stops as soon as I press the scroll view and it continues to run after I release the scroll.

Is there a configuration for NSTimer such that timer is not blocked during scrolling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1707977?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684016/why-timer-stops-when-scrolling-in-uiwebview-iphone

Comment: @iPatel, thanks for the links, now I can look at the subject in depth

Answer (score 14):

Add this single line and try again please

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```