# uiscrollview doesn't update content on scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, refresh

I have `UIViews` with animations inside `UIScrollViews` and when I scroll the animations are not updated. The changes are being made with `NSTimers`.

Is there any know cause for this to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView pauses NSTimer until scrolling finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605027/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-until-scrolling-finishes)

Answer (score 0):

Alloc your own timers, add them to the the run loop yourself in the NSRunLoopCommonModes

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

NSRunLoopCommonModes
Objects added to a run loop using this value as the mode are monitored by all run loop modes that have been declared as a member of the set of “common" modes; see the description of CFRunLoopAddCommonMode for details.
Available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.