# Why does UIScrollView pause my CADisplayLink?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uikit, cadisplaylink, caeagllayer

I have a view backed by a CAEAGLLayer, which is inside a UIScrollView. When I begin scrolling, the CADisplayLink that calls the -draw method of openGL view stops getting called.

I verified that my runloop start / stop methods don't get called when scrolling. The -draw method simply doesn't get called as soon as scrolling begins, and resumes getting called as soon as scrolling ends.

Does UIKit stop a CADisplayLink from firing as soon as scrolling starts?

The display link is added to the run loop like this:

```
[dl addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Maybe there is a conflict with this run loop mode and UIScrollView? Are there other run loop modes or alternative solutions to keep a CADisplayLink firing even when a UIScrollView is scrolling?

I thought there can be more than just one CADisplayLink in any application. Is that wrong?

Comment: It would seem that this is the solution currently (2016) ... stackoverflow.com/a/4878182/294884 ... which I believe is what rickster explains at length.  Note that QA on this issue is quite confusing, as Apple screwed everything up, and the behaviors have changed drastically over the years.

Answer (score 33):

You're not in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` while scrolling a `UIScrollView`; you're in `UITrackingRunLoopMode`. So any timer scheduled only for the former won't fire in the latter.  You can add your `CADisplayLink` to multiple run loop modes by calling `addToRunLoop:forMode:` repeatedly, or call it once with `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, which covers both modes.

They talked about this in detail, and other issues with integrating scroll views with GL, at WWDC 2012 in Session 223: "Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views"; I recommend watching the [video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), as there's lots of other stuff in there that's likely relevant to your situation.

---

An example in (2016) Swift3...

```
let d = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(ThisClassName.updateAlpha))
d.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)


//and then, for example...
func updateAlpha() {
  let a = leader.layer.presentation()?.value(forKey: "opacity") as! CGFloat
  follower.alpha = a
  }
```

Comment: So what can I do about it? How can I schedule a timer for multiple modes so it also fires while scrolling? Just two calls to -addToRunLoop:forMode: ?

Comment: Indeed @rickster regarding this issue, years later, it does seem to be pretty stable now. `.commonModes` finally seems to "just work".  I edited in a Swift3 example, obviously feel free to delete/edit

Comment: 1. Are you adding a new mode the current RunLoops mode? 2. If that's the main thread does that mean that you've added a new mode to the main thread's modes?  Hence that mode won't be removed from it until the app is killed? Which basically means that the app will do a heaver kind of tracking events? I'm asking because I read From [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542137-cfrunloopaddcommonmode) "Once a mode is added to the set of common modes, it cannot be removed." meaning you can't remove that mode...