# Multiple uiscrollviews, issues with scrolling

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have an iPad application showing finance information such as stock data information and stock related feeds. Stock data information displayed is an auto scrolling stock ticker shown in a UIScrollView. Stock related feeds are also displayed as auto scrolling cyclic view with another UIScrollView. Both these views can be scrolled manually also.

Issue is that, when the user manually scrolls one of the scrollview; for example, scrolling through the feeds scrollview, the stock ticker scrollview stops automatically. When the stock ticker  is scrolled manually, the feeds scrollview stops. The view also has a table view, which when scrolled stops both the autoscrolling views (feed & stock). I have implemented delegate methods of scrollview and actions are defined by checking for specific scrollview inside the delegate methods.

I am using a timer that runs a UIViewanimation to autoscroll stock ticker.

Is this the default behaviour of UIScrollview? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.. thanks to this post.. [UIScrollView pauses NSTimer until scrolling finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605027/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-until-scrolling-finishes)

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:... 
                                         target:...
                                       selector:....
                                       userInfo:...
                                        repeats:...];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=67