# UISlider Pauses when UIScrollView is Scrolled

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uislider

In my iOS app, I have a `UISlider` that is added to my app's window.

```
var window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.insertSubview(slider, at: 0)
window.bringSubview(toFront: slider)
```

This `UISlider` gets updated every 0.1 seconds (It's showing the current length of a video and it's updated by a `Timer`) One of my `ViewControllers` contains a `UIScrollView` and when that `UIScrollView` is scrolled, the `UISlider` pauses updating. When the user finishes scrolling, the `UISlider` starts updating normally, again. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605027/uiscrollview-pauses-nstimer-until-scrolling-finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that scrolling of `UIScrollView` causes suspension of `NSTimer`. So, it's not related with your `UISlider`.

To fix this, after initialiazation your `NSTimer` add timer to `RunLoop.main` for mode `RunLoopMode.commonModes`

```
RunLoop.main.add(yourTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```